# How to access Xamarin UITest methods case /Methods from python?

Tags: python, xamarin, nunit

we are trying to access Xamarin UITest methods from python, currently Xamarin UITest is running on nunit hence we are not able to access the Xamarin UiTest methods from python, is there any way to achieve this task ?

Note : we were able to access general C# methods from python using clr , but we see this issue when we are using nunit, is there any way to achieve this task ?

Thanks in advance.